# How to preserve the zoom state with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to draw a graph based on some input values. Once the graph is drawn, I zoom the graph by dragging the mouse. Now, I change the input values and draw the graph again based on the new input values supplied by me. I want the graph should come in the last zoom state which I zoomed earlier.

I have used the following, but is always coming to center and some other zoom position.

```
double zoomX = chartPanel.getScaleX();
double zoomX = chartPanel.getScaleX();
chartPanel.zoomInBoth(zoomX, zoomY);
```

Can anyone help me in this, how to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.